# Поиск одинаковых строк в текстовом файле

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Имеется база вида (Где есть повторяющиеся строки):

```
+Результат
+Ошибка
+Результат
+Результат
+Результат
+Ошибка
......
```

Нужно посчитать все повторяющиеся строки **что расположены в текстовом файле** и вывести отчет в Memo1. Результат должен получится в Memo1 такой:

```
+Результат - 4 раза
+Ошибка - 2 раза
```

**То есть посчитать все одинаковые строки что есть в текстовом файле и статистику вывести в Memo1.**

Предоставленный код работает быстро но вот при размерах файла в 600 мегабайт выдает сообщение о нехватке памяти. Ну это и понятно потому как мы все грузим в память.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TS: TStringList;
  s, OneWord: string;
  i, Cnt: integer;
begin
  TS := TStringList.Create;
  TS.Delimiter := '+';
  TS.LoadFromFile('baza.txt');
  s := TS.Text;
  TS.DelimitedText := s;

  if TS.Count = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Вообще ни одного слова нет!');
    Exit;
  end;

  TS.Sort;

  Memo1.Lines.Clear; // подготовим место для формирования отчёта

  // собственно подсчёт
  OneWord := TS.Strings[0];
  Cnt := 1;
  for i := 1 to TS.Count - 1 do
    if AnsiUpperCase(TS.Strings[i]) = AnsiUpperCase(OneWord) then
      inc(Cnt)
    else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Append(OneWord + '+' + InttoStr(Cnt));
      OneWord := TS.Strings[i];
      Cnt := 1;
    end;

  // для последнего слова в списке вывод результата
  Memo1.Lines.Append(OneWord + '+' + InttoStr(Cnt));

  FreeAndNil(TS); // освободим память
end;
```

**Пробовала оформить код через  AssignFile - чтение построчно но у меня тут ошибки. Помогите исправить ?**

```
var
  TS: TStringList;
  s,st: string;
  i, Cnt: integer;
  f1: TextFile;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear; // подготовим место для формирования отчёта

  // Открываем диалог выбора файла
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then
    exit
  else
    AssignFile(f1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  reset(f1);

  TS := TStringList.Create;
  TS.Delimiter := '+';
  s := TS.Text;
  TS.DelimitedText := s;
  TS.Sort;

  if TS.Count = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Вообще ни одного слова нет!');
    exit;
  end;

  While not EOF(f1) do
  begin
    // Что бы программа не подвисала
    Application.ProcessMessages();
    readln(f1, st);
    TS.Add(st);

    // собственно подсчёт
    st := TS.Strings[0];
    Cnt := 1;
    for i := 1 to TS.Count - 1 do
      if AnsiUpperCase(TS.Strings[i]) = AnsiUpperCase(st) then
        inc(Cnt)
      else
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Append(st + '-' + InttoStr(Cnt));
        st := TS.Strings[i];
        Cnt := 1;
      end;

    // для последнего слова в списке вывод результата
    Memo1.Lines.Append(st + '-' + InttoStr(Cnt));

    FreeAndNil(TS); // освободим память

  end;

  TS.Free;
  CloseFile(f1);

end;
```

Comment: 1. У TStringList есть метод IndexOf

Comment: 2. Если предположить, что размер файла очень большой и все строки разные, то нехватка памяти возникнет в обоих случаях.
3. Можно, например, создавать отдельный файл для каждой строчки и писать в него кол-во повторений. Но, опять же (см. п2) в этом случае может получиться слишком много файлов, что, впрочем, решаемо.
4. Можно перенести строки из файла в БД и потом выполнить один SQL-запрос

Comment: Если же файл содержит строки исключительно 2-х типов ("+Результат" и "+Ошибка"), то можно поступить просто:  
1. Создать TStringList (TS)  
2. Читать cтроку из файла (SFF)  
2. Проверять TS.IndexOfName(SFF)  
3. Если найден, то увеличивать TS.Values[SFF] на 1  
Т.о. в TS сразу получится требуемый результат

Comment: @OldSkull Только лучше через Objects[] делать, а не через Values[], будет намного быстрее.

Comment: @Alekcvp, возможно. Только Objects надо инициализировать, освобождать потом. Да и чтение с диска, наверное, медленнее работы с памятью. Надо общее время замерять, если это целесообразно в рамках данной задачи. А ещё, наверное, можно TDictionary<String, Integer> попробовать применить. В XE он уже должен присутствовать.

Comment: У вас в тэгах куча версий Delphi. Оставьте delphi и одну актуальную версию. От неё может зависеть решение

Comment: @MBo, Исправила теги, В целом использую RAD Studio 10.1. Но задачу так и не смогла решить через AssignFile чтением построчно.

Comment: @OldSkull, Objects не надо инициализировать если хранить там просто число. `TS.Objects[Index] := TObject(NativeInt(TS.Objects[Index]) + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  Dict: TDictionary<string, integer>;
  f: TextFile;
  s:string;
  cnt: Integer;
  A: TArray<TPair<string, integer>>;
  p: TPair<string, integer>;
begin
  Dict := TDictionary<string, integer>.Create;
  AssignFile(f, 'e:\s.txt');
  Reset(f);
  while not EOF(f) do begin
    Readln(f, s);
    Dict.TryGetValue(s, cnt);
    Dict.AddOrSetValue(s, cnt + 1);
  end;
  CloseFile(f);
//  for s in dict.Keys do
//    Memo1.Lines.Add(s + ': ' +Dict.Items[s].ToString);
  A:=  Dict.ToArray;
   TArray.Sort<TPair<string, Integer>>(A,
    TComparer<TPair<string, Integer>>.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TPair<string, Integer>): Integer
      begin
        Result := -CompareStr(L.Key, R.Key);
      end)
  );
  for p in A do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(p.Key + ': ' + p.Value.ToString);
  Dict.Free;
```

Comment: Идеальный вариант и файл в моем случае в 600 мегабайт обработался свободно! Спасибо за код сейчас изучу его полностью.

Comment: А еще такой вопрос: А что бы сделать сортировку результатов по убыванию, по цифрам. То есть что бы в Memo результаты отображались от большего числа и по убыванию. То есть в столбик сначала идет там где самое большое число а потом меньше и меньше +Результат - 4 раза
+Ошибка - 2 раза.

Comment: Внутри словаря этого сделать нельзя - нужно извлечь в массив пары строка-счётчик и отсортировать его по полю счётчика

Comment: А если отсортировать напрямую в Memo, при нажатии отдельной кнопки. То есть когда уже в Memo получили результат. После обработка отдельно по нажатию на кнопку 2. Если не сложно то как можно это сделать, пример, самый простой.

Comment: Заменил код....

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь буду смотреть все нюансы и обязательно досконально изучу код.